# Binary output with tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, deep-learning, tflearn

I am begginer with tflearn/tensorflow. 
I'm making a DNN to classify heartbeat in **Normal** **(0)** or **Arrhytmia** **(1)**. My dataset is [ECG by MIT Arrhytmia Dataset](https://www.physionet.org/physiobank/database/mitdb/) ..

I build this following net:

```
## Build neural network
net = tflearn.input_data(shape=[None, 200])
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 400)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 400)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 100)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 50)
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='linear')
net = tflearn.regression(net, optimizer='adam', learning_rate=0.01,loss='mean_square', name='target')
##
## Define model
model = tflearn.DNN(net)
print('fiting')
model.fit(TrainSet, labelSet, n_epoch=5000, batch_size=len(TrainSet), show_metric=True)
```

My output is:

```
y pred                   y target
predict:[0.01360663]      [0]
predict:[0.00861748]      [0]
predict:[-0.00685573]     [0]
predict:[-0.20846206]     [1]
```

My network is separating well, the output for a Normal sample `(predict:[0.00861748]      [0])` is quite different from the output of an arrhythmia sample `(predict:[-0.20846206]     [1])`

So, how can i make the output is only `0` or `1` else this float values?
Maybe changing my activiation function? or make something with my actual output?

this is my output when i do: `model.predict(TrainingSet)`

```
y predicted             y target
predict:[-0.138634]     [0]
predict:[-0.13436639]     [0]
predict:[-0.12879151]     [0]
predict:[-0.12057236]     [0]
predict:[-0.13836551]     [0]
predict:[-0.08525576]     [0]
predict:[ 1.01741135]     [1]
predict:[-0.11624834]     [0]
predict:[-0.12631142]     [0]
predict:[-0.11693959]     [0]
predict:[-0.10779606]     [0]
predict:[-0.11510199]     [0]
predict:[-0.12450527]     [0]
predict:[-0.12869376]     [0]
predict:[-0.15167347]     [0]
predict:[-0.14081171]     [0]
predict:[-0.14235598]     [0]
predict:[-0.13095573]     [0]
predict:[-0.12757528]     [0]
predict:[-0.14675851]     [0]
predict:[-0.12311366]     [0]
predict:[-0.15386838]     [0]
predict:[-0.17505151]     [0]
predict:[-0.13848163]     [0]
predict:[-0.11671469]     [0]
predict:[-0.13247125]     [0]
predict:[-0.13718334]     [0]
predict:[-0.12702732]     [0]
predict:[-0.12665084]     [0]
predict:[-0.1367469]     [0]
predict:[-0.15925398]     [0]
predict:[-0.13639028]     [0]
predict:[-0.11569472]     [0]
predict:[-0.14167]     [0]
predict:[-0.12262306]     [0]
predict:[-0.10863069]     [0]
predict:[-0.14324963]     [0]
predict:[-0.14792402]     [0]
predict:[-0.14929616]     [0]
predict:[-0.15551159]     [0]
predict:[-0.11816701]     [0]
predict:[-0.11785387]     [0]
predict:[-0.15215725]     [0]
predict:[-0.11279716]     [0]
predict:[-0.1469961]     [0]
predict:[-0.14991215]     [0]
predict:[-0.11661309]     [0]
predict:[-0.09011015]     [0]
predict:[-0.09775476]     [0]
predict:[-0.1065342]     [0]
predict:[-0.11091903]     [0]
predict:[-0.10344772]     [0]
predict:[-0.12412915]     [0]
predict:[-0.13605709]     [0]
predict:[-0.12797417]     [0]
predict:[-0.1076207]     [0]
predict:[-0.12150024]     [0]
predict:[-0.13840012]     [0]
predict:[-0.13084875]     [0]
predict:[-0.11066008]     [0]
predict:[-0.12374203]     [0]
predict:[-0.13341869]     [0]
predict:[-0.12912038]     [0]
predict:[-0.13748281]     [0]
predict:[-0.13966258]     [0]
predict:[-0.13894111]     [0]
predict:[-0.10213074]     [0]
predict:[-0.15602994]     [0]
predict:[-0.12982219]     [0]
predict:[-0.09376201]     [0]
predict:[-0.08830833]     [0]
predict:[-0.12029025]     [0]
predict:[-0.09362413]     [0]
predict:[ 1.09521723]     [1]
predict:[-0.13147078]     [0]
predict:[-0.1182971]     [0]
predict:[-0.12983324]     [0]
predict:[-0.18321729]     [0]
predict:[-0.18334746]     [0]
predict:[-0.2399022]     [0]
```

Comment: I am not familiar with the dataset, but it seems to me that the seperation isn't all that great... I would have thought that the 3rd result in your output would be `[1]` because it is negative. However, it's impossible to notice any pattern from only 4 examples that you provided.

Comment: you can change your activation to sigmoid.

Comment: You seem to be misusing the activation functions of the network. It's odd that you are using MSE as the loss function while having the network having a linear activation in the last layer. Unfortunately, explaining this matter is off-topic in SO. Consider doing further research on neural networks (including about typical activation functions and loss functions), and ultimately adapting and moving your question to [Cross Validated](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45132744/1233251).

Comment: Thanks to the reply, i change my net to: `net = flearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid')` 
`net = tflearn.regression(net,optimizer='adam',loss='binary_crossentropy')`

Comment: That would be inappropriate too: binary cross entropy expects a logit as the input from the network, and you gave it a neuron with a sigmoid activation. You may find that using "linear" for the last neuron with 'binary_crossentropy' works better. See also these questions from other Stack Exchange sites: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/260505/67965 https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/9302/the-cross-entropy-error-function-in-neural-networks

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is changing your activation function to 'softmax' and rounding the predictions. You can do it by;

```
net = tflearn.fully_connected(net, 1, activation='sigmoid ')
```

and predict with:

```
pred = model.predict(test_data)     
print([ np.where(r==1)[0][0] for r in np.round(pred)])
```

That should work.

Comment: A softmax activation over a single neuron doesn't make sense. You probably meant `tflearn.fully_connected(net, 2, activation='softmax')`, and that would only work for 2 exclusive classes.